# Codeigniter cannot connect to server --google sync failed

Tags: php, codeigniter, google-calendar-api, synchronization

I am modifying this code in a controller for synchronization with google calendar.  The following is the original that gives no errors and synchronizes fine:

```
        // :: ADD GCAL EVENTS THAT ARE NOT PRESENT ON E!A
        $google_calendar = $provider['settings']['google_calendar'];
        $events = $this->google_sync->get_sync_events($google_calendar, $start, $end);

        foreach($events->getItems() as $event) {
            $results = $this->appointments_model->get_batch(array('id_google_calendar' => $event->getId()));
            if (count($results) == 0) {
                // Record doesn't exist in E!A, so add the event now.

                $appointment = array(

                    'start_datetime' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($event->start->getDateTime())),
                    'end_datetime' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($event->end->getDateTime())),
                    'is_unavailable' => TRUE,
                    'notes' => $event->getSummary() . ' ' .$event->getDescription(),
                    'id_users_provider' => $provider_id,
                    'id_google_calendar' => $event->getId(),
                    'id_users_customer' => NULL,
                    'id_services' => NULL,
                );

                $this->appointments_model->add($appointment);
            }
        }
```

The following is the code with my modifications.  It produces a server connection error.

```
        // :: ADD GCAL EVENTS THAT ARE NOT PRESENT ON E!A
        $google_calendar = $provider['settings']['google_calendar'];
        $events = $this->google_sync->get_sync_events($google_calendar, $start, $end);

        foreach($events->getItems() as $event) {
            $results = $this->appointments_model->get_batch(array('id_google_calendar' => $event->getId()));
            if (count($results) == 0) {
                // Record doesn't exist in E!A, so add the event now.

             $str = $event->getDescription()
             $expnote = explode('|',$str)

                $appointment = array(

                    'start_datetime' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($event->start->getDateTime())),
                    'end_datetime' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($event->end->getDateTime())),
                    'is_unavailable' => TRUE,
                    'notes' => $event->getSummary() . ' ' . $expnote[0],
                    'id_users_provider' => $provider_id,
                    'id_google_calendar' => $event->getId(),
                    'id_users_customer' => $expnote[2],
                    'id_services' => $expnote[1],
                );

                $this->appointments_model->add($appointment);
            }
        }
```

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: can you please post your error description?

Comment: It comes from the error handling in easy!appointments backend when I start sync.  It just says  "Google synchronization failed. Could not establish server connection."  I do not see anything in the Apache error log, I do not see anything in the php error log in easy!appointments.  What I notice is that if I put any code in the line above  or below  $appointment = array( the sync is halted.  So, I am thinking something is not matching up in another library or model somewhere.  I am looking but I am not sure what for.

Comment: I looked in the browser for Java Script errors:  Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)